# vue ref$ undefined (in child vue2-dropzone)

Tags: vue.js, dropzone

I have this template

```
<VueDropzone
      id="drop1"
      ref="dropzoneBlock"
      :options="dropOptions"
    ></VueDropzone>

    <button class="drop__button" @click="onSubmitFiles">send</button>
```

and this script in method

```
onSubmitFiles(){
     console.log(this.$refs.dropzoneBlock.processQueue()); 
 },
```

and in dropzone options

```
dropOptions: {
        url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
        maxFilesize: 10, // MB
        maxFiles: 20,
        chunking: true,
        chunkSize: 500, // Bytes
        thumbnailWidth: 200, // px
        thumbnailHeight: 150,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        
      }
```

So when I try to Send, console give me 'undefined'

But if I change code to

```
onSubmitFiles(){
     console.log(this.$refs.dropzoneBlock); 
 }
```

console give me an object.
and if I inspect the object I see method 'processQueue()'

I try everything from internet

```
/ nextTick 
/ timeOut
/ I don't have v-if or v-show on page (only in package from plugin, component have v-if on slot) 
/ this.$refs.dropzoneBlock.dropzone.processQueue()
```

Also right now if I make in options

```
autoProcessQueue: true
```

thats no work.
But everything in drop zone work fine, but I cant just send file to server

Please any help

Answer (score 0):

If your method `this.$refs.dropzoneBlock.processQueue()` return nothing then you will get `undefined` in your console. Try to return something from `processQueue()` or just call `console.log('processQueue() called')` inside your `processQueue()` method.

**UPD.** Maybe this will be helpful:

> This should maybe in the docs. In master Vue its
> this.$refs.fileUploadZone.processQueue(); in template
> this.$refs.fileUploadZone.dropzone.processQueue();

from here https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone/issues/54#issuecomment-317559860

So, try to use

```
this.$refs.dropzoneBlock.dropzone.processQueue()
```

instead of `this.$refs.dropzoneBlock.processQueue()`.